# The probability of a game card drawing system

Tags: probability

In a game card drawing system, there is a $0.006 = 0.6\%$ chance to get a SSR (i.e super super rare) card and the game have a rule that in every $70$ draw the player is guarantee to obtain at least $1$ SSR card. So, what is the probability that a player draw a SSR card on his $50$th draw.

Let $P(A)$ be "the probability a player draw a SSR card on his $x$-th draw"
Then, $P(A^c)$ is the probability that a player did not obtain any SSR cards throughout his $49$ pull.
Also, because there is a $0.006 = 0.6\%$ chance to get a SSR card which this implies $0.994=99.4\%$ the cance I will not get a SSR card.
$\textbf{So, my question is that}$
(1) is the probability $P(A) = 1 - \frac{(70-50)\times0.994}{70}=0.716$ ?
(2) is the the probability of a player draw a SSR card on his $50$th draw same if now the rule change to every $70$ draw the player is guarantee to obtain at $\textbf{exactly}$ $1$ SSR card ? (if not, then what is the probability in this case ?)

Comment: It is not clear how the guarantee operates, if there were no guarantee, P(draw on $50^{th}$ card) is easy to find using the negative binomial distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a game card drawing system, there is a 0.006=0.6% chance to get a SSR (i.e super super rare) card and the game have a rule that in every 70 draw the player is guarantee to obtain at least 1 SSR card. So, what is the probability that a player draw a SSR card on his 50th draw.

I am unsure how to interpret this question.  For example, suppose that on the first draw, the player gets the SSR card.  Does this mean that the player then **stops** drawing?  If so, then the information that the player will get a SSR card on the 70th draw seems redundant.

As I see it, there are $2$ plausible ways of interpreting the problem: listed below.  Note that there may also be other equally plausible ways, that I am overlooking.

- Option-1 
  All draws up until the 70th draw are independent events, where it is as if the card is drawn with replacement.  The probability of success on any one draw is $0.006$.  If at any time, before draw 70, the player draws the SSR card, the drawing stops. 
  Under this interpretation, let $p = 0.006, q = (1-p)$.  Then, the only way of drawing the SSR card on draw $50$ is if you first fail to draw the SSR card prior to that.
  Probability will be $q^{49} \times p.$
- Option-2
  Regardless of whether the player draws an SSR at any time prior to (for example) draw $70$, he will still continue to draw at least $69$ times.
  Under this interpretation, the probability of drawing the SSR on draw $50$ is the same as the probability of drawing the SSR on draw $1$.  
  Namely $p = 0.006$.

---

There may be other ways of interpeting the problem than those given above.  Clearly, either the OP (i.e. original poster) has omitted information needed to resolve the problem's ambiguity, or the problem composer has omitted information needed to resolve the problem's ambiguity.